# How to pass data from VC to another by skipping tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a Main VC which has a connection to Tab Bar Controller via segue and that Tab Bar controller has 2 sections and those are 2 ViewControllers. I need to pass data from Main VC to that specific VC which derived from Tab Bar Controller using segue. Since i am able to use only one segue (to show only TBController), is there any way to achieve to pass data directly from main to another by skipping Tab Bar controller?

Ps. Those 2 VC have a navigation controller connection between Tab Bar Controller and themselves as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  var secondTab = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers[1] as SecondViewController
  secondTab.array = firstArray
```

Comment: nope this way is not working. Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' to 'UINavigationController'..

Answer (score 0):

On prepare for segue function you can get the tabBar associated controllers  via TabBarControllers property `viewControllers` - that let you select one of a tab bar controller's view controllers to become the active view controller. then you use tabBarController's property `selectedIndex` to actually segue to that VC.

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let index = 0//the index of the tab you wish to segue to
            if let bar = segue.destination as? TabBarVC {
               if let nav = bar.viewControllers[index] as?  UINavigationController {
                 if let navChildVC = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as? YourVCType { // index of the controller of enumerate to find it
             // pass data to navChildVC
                   bar.selectedIndex = index
           }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: i cant pass data with`nav.somedata =somedata` like that since it is navigation controller

Comment: same as tabbar use:  let navChildVC = navigationController.viewControllers[0] I also edited my answer